# Trigger parameterized Jenkins job from groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Hello Jenkins friends,

I created a Jenkins Freestyle project that contains the step "Execute Groovy Script". From the script, I want to trigger another parameterized job on the same Jenkins server.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

```
def triggerBuild(paramter1, paramter2) {
   // trigger job with name "foo" and set the paramters param1 and param2 
   //to the values of the variables parameter1 and parameter2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally got a solution. My script looks as follows:

```
import hudson.model.*;

triggerBuild()

def triggerBuild(parameter1, parameter2) {
    def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('foo')

    def params = [
            new StringParameterValue('param1', 'value1'),
            new StringParameterValue('param1', 'value2')
    ]
    def future = job.scheduleBuild2(0,  new ParametersAction(params))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def triggerBuild(parameter1, parameter2) {
  build job: 'foo', parameters: [
    string(name: 'param1', value: parameter1),
    string(name: 'param2', value: parameter2),
  ]
}
```

Be sure to invoke `triggerBuild()` inside `script` block.

Comment: thx
yes it is running in whole groovy-script file that is included via 'Execute groovy script'  in the 'build' section of the job configuration. Do I have to import any packages? Your solution leads to the result that my class has no method called 'build'

Comment: You have to call it from inside the Jenkins pipeline — see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Comment: there's no other possibility? As I have freestyle project, I do not have a scripted pipeline